# General OO in CFML: Is it possible to dynamically extend a CFC?

Tags: inheritance, coldfusion

(I may be on the wrong track from the start here, so my question title may need editing...)

For an ecommerce app, I have a StoreBase CFC, and "subclass" CFCs StoreCheckout, StoreCart and other modules/objects within the app.

Some clients have module specific biz logic, so we create CFCs with custom functionality as needed -- eg StoreCartClientX extends StoreCart and overrides some calculation.

Some clients also have custom base biz logic -- eg StoreBaseClientX extends StoreBase and restricts access to certain parts of the app based on custom rules.

My problem is that I need a way to tell StoreCart to extend StoreBaseClientX when StoreBaseClientX exists which would seem to require dynamic extension and that seems like a bad idea based on various posts (taken on faith) in SO (and in anycase, I'm using ColdFusion (go ahead, laugh) and dynamic expressions are not allowed for extension.)

Here's some psuedo code to illustrate the problem.

```
public class StoreBase {
    checkRights(){
      //standard rights check
    }

    findWishList(){
   }
}

public class StoreBaseClientX extends storeBase {
       checkRights(){
         //custom rights check for ClientX
       }
}


   public class StoreCart extends StoreBase { //if StoreBaseClientX exists, it should extend that instead


   }
```

Comment: The answer to your question depends on which programming language you are using. I guess it's Java. Is my guess correct?

Comment: "(and in anycase, I'm using ColdFusion (go ahead, laugh) and dynamic expressions are not allowed for extension.)"

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can make use of a static factory to create the class for you.

Long answer: From what I read so far, I think you should familiar yourself with the strategy pattern.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance.

Comment: I based my original design (as best I could, anyway) on a type-object pattern, which seems similar. In any case, I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around a real world example. I'm adding a better pseudo code example to the question to work from.

Comment: @jdb I think you should read up the strategy pattern on a good book like Head First Design Pattern, I think you will find it useful. :)

Comment: Funny. Yeah, just ordered from amazon. Am I demonstrating such a lack of knowledge that it's not worth diving into? :)... I'll take my learnin' where I can get it, if you feel like offering...

Comment: @jdb Once you understand the concept of behavior can be injected dynamically, you'll see this problem you have in a different way.

Comment: @jdb Instead of ordering the actual book, you may consider Google Play so you can read it right away, or safaribooksonline.com.

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this would be to *always* include StoreBaseClient, rather than trying to make it's existence optional. Just ship StoreBaseClient as an empty stub class that can be customized by the client as needed. Example components:

```
<cfcomponent name="StoreBase">
   <!--- your code --->
</cfcomponent>

<cfcomponent name="StoreBaseClient" extends="StoreBase">
   <!--- empty --->
</cfcomponent>

<cfcomponent name="StoreCart" extends="StoreBaseClient">
   <!--- your code --->
</cfcomponent>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Not sure this will work. StoreBaseClient is meant to be custom for any particular client. EG StoreBaseClientX won't have the same custom overrides as StoreBaseClientY. And StoreCart needs to know which StoreBaseClientN to extend. It's sort of a poor man's decorator pattern, where instead of referencing the base class in the decorator object, I just extend it. But any external references to, say, storeBase > checkLogin() do not need to know whether the base method or a subclass method is being called.

Comment: So are you hosting multiple stores from the same code base, then? My answer makes less sense in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, is the inheritance model you're using where both `StoreCheckout` and `StoreCart` extend `StoreBase` correct? It seems unlikely to me that `StoreBase` is such that one could say `StoreCheckout` **is a** `StoreBase` as well as `StoreCart` **is a** `StoreBase`? What are example methods in both? Are you sure `StoreCheckout` and `StoreCart` oughtn't be such that each **has a** `StoreBase` (ie: the `StoreBase` object is something the other classes are init'ed with)?

But anyway, that's just something to think about, and tangential to your issue. Maybe pop something on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for us to look at, if you like?

I'd turn things around a bit, as Russ says. instead of having to work out whether a client-specific sub-component exists and then if it does, use that instead of the base component, you should *always* have the client-customisable sub-component, and always reference those ones in your code, and never the base components.

In short, though, one cannot have a dynamic/runtime `extends` attribute on a component in ColdFusion, no. It has to be there at compile time.

Comment: I'm concerned about class explosion if I subclass for every client. That said, i take your point about reconsidering the relationship between StoreCheckout and StoreBase -- it's not really a Is A relationship. Maybe some IOC solution would be smart here. That's not something I'm terribly familiar with either-- In coldspring for example, can you build your objects at runtime based on some condition? Does that make sense?